# How to get the difference between execution start time and execution end time in plsql

Tags: plsql

How to get the difference between execution start time and execution end time in plsql.

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  l_start_time DATE :=sysdate +1;
  l_end_time DATE   := SYSDATE;
  to_hours DATE;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(l_start_time);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_end_time);
  TO_HOURS:=TO_CHAR(L_END_TIME - to_date(L_START_TIME,'HH24:MI:SS'));
  dbms_output.put_line (TO_HOURS);
END ;
```

I need the execution time difference and the output to be in `HH:MI:SS`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME function.
This function determines the current time in 100th's of a second. This subprogram is primarily used for determining elapsed time. The subprogram is called twice – at the beginning and end of some process – and then the first (earlier) number is subtracted from the second (later) number to determine the time elapsed. For example:

```
declare 
  v_end_time        number(10) ; 
  v_start_time      number(10) ; 
begin
   v_start_time := dbms_utility.get_time ;
   -- <Your code is here>
   null;
   --<\Your code is here>
   v_end_time :=  dbms_utility.get_time   ;

   dbms_output.put_line(  'Elapse Time= '|| to_char( (v_end_time - v_start_time) /100 ) ||' seconds.' );
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the difference as a number and then calculate it from the fractions of the day. The following example script gives the below output

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  l_start_time date := sysdate;
  l_end_time   date := SYSDATE+1;
  l_diff       number;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('start time='||l_start_time);
  dbms_output.put_line('end time  ='||l_end_time);
  l_diff :=l_end_time-l_start_time;
  dbms_output.put_line('a) difference days   ='||to_char(l_diff));
  dbms_output.put_line('a) difference hours  ='||to_char(l_diff*24));
  dbms_output.put_line('a) difference minutes='||to_char(l_diff*24*60));
  dbms_output.put_line('a) difference seconds='||to_char(l_diff*24*60*60));
  l_start_time := to_date('31/07/2012 20:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
  l_end_time   := to_date('01/08/2012 04:15:44','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
  l_diff :=l_end_time-l_start_time;
  dbms_output.put_line('b) difference days   ='||to_char(l_diff));
  dbms_output.put_line('b) difference hours  ='||to_char(l_diff*24));
  dbms_output.put_line('b) difference minutes='||to_char(l_diff*24*60));
  dbms_output.put_line('b) difference seconds='||to_char(l_diff*24*60*60));
END ;
/
```

Outputs to:

```
start time=31-JUL-12
end time  =01-AUG-12
a) difference days   =1
a) difference hours  =24
a) difference minutes=1440
a) difference seconds=86400
b) difference days   =.3442592592592592592592592592592592592593
b) difference hours  =8.26222222222222222222222222222222222222
b) difference minutes=495.733333333333333333333333333333333333
b) difference seconds=29744
```

Answer (score -1):

try please the follow code

```
TO_HOURS:= L_END_TIME - L_START_TIME;
dbms_output.put_line (to_char(TO_HOURS, "your format"));
```

Comment: to_hours must not be of type date. The above gives an error PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type